# Como pasar un ListBox a una variable de módulo (VBA) (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy haciendo una macro en Excel, pero para tener más localizable el código prefiero hacer todo en los módulos y en los UserForm solamente llamar otros procedimientos.

Trabajando con un ListBox cuando el código estaba dentro de un botón del UserForm con la referencia *Me.ListBox1* podía modificarla, pero no puedo usar *Me* en un módulo, intenté hacer una variable Object y una UserForm para pasarle la referencia pero no me permite

```
Sub LlenarListBox()

       Dim ReferenciaListBox1 As UserForm '(Utilicé también tipo Object)        
       Set ReferenciaListBox1 = UserForm1.ListBox1

       ReferenciaListBox1.AddItem
       ReferenciaListBox1.List(0, 0) = Hoja1.Cells(2, 1).Value

End Sub
```

El problema es que cuando corro el código me da el error

> Se ha producido el error '13' en tiempo de ejecución
> No coinciden los tipos

Adicional a saber esto, ¿creen conveniente esta práctica o debo dispersar el código?

Comment: Probaste con `Dim ReferenciaListBox1 as Listbox`? El error 13 significa que estás metiendo un valor/objeto en una variable que no admite ese tipo de valores/objetos. Por ejemplo, un texto en una variable que solo admite números.

Answer (score 1):

Al procedimiento `LlenarListBox` le puedes pasar como parámetro el formulario.

Ejemplo:

```
Sub LlenarListBox(form As frmTest)
    form.lstTest.AddItem Hoja1.Cells(2, 1).Value
End Sub
```

El formulario se llama `frmTest` y el listbox se llama `lstTest`

El el formulario puedes llamar esa función de la siguiente manera.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Util.LlenarListBox Me
End Sub
```

En este caso lo he llamado desde el evento `Initialize`, pero puedes ejecutarlo en otro procedimiento.

`Util` es el nombre del modulo donde esta `LlenarListBox`, no es necesario escribir el nombre del modulo para llamar al procedimiento, pero si en el modulo tienes varios procedimientos, al escribir el nombre del modulo y el punto, te mostrara todos esos procedimientos para auto-completar.